# android Listview single item in dialog fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

- I have to show listview single item in dialog one by one. Its like a number
  of questions for a quiz which will be generated dynamically.
- List row view contains questions text, few radio buttons and at
  bottom there are three buttons next, previous and save. Besides
  bottoms buttons every thing is dynamic.